# i want to make 10 directories and file in each directory using while loop

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, directory

I want to make 10 directories and in each directory there should be a 1 file how can i make such code using while and for loop.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? To make a directory, use `mkdir`. To make a file, `touch`. In Bash, you can do this without a loop: `mkdir dir{1..10}; touch dir{1..10}/file`.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the below command for this:**

```
#!/bin/bash
a=1
while [[ $a -lt 11 ]];do
    mkdir dir${a}
    touch dir${a}/file${a}
    ((a++))
done
exit
```

Comment: I would use a simpler loop, such as `for i in {1..10}; do mkdir... touch...; done`. However, as I pointed out in my comment to the question, the loop is not even necessary. In case the shell does not support the `{...}` syntax, `for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` does the trick.